# How many words can a tag contain?

Tags: discussion, tags

This came up when asking a question just now.

Without scraping the data dump, I'd guess that tags have at most 3 words.  I'm wondering if this is enforced or not?

I just asked a question about sql server compact 3.5 sp1.  Most related questions are tagged sql-server-ce, which isn't exactly an appropriate tag, as Sql Server CE used to be FOR CE until it was brought to the desktop as Sql Server Compact.  The official name of the latest version is Sql Server Compact 3.5 SP1, which I want to tag my question with.

Now, should I tag it sql-server-compact3.5sp1, sql-server-compact-3.5-sp1, or something else?

I suppose this question could not only be about tag word counts but also version numbers in tags.  Any guidance on this subject is appreciated

Comment: If it's not at least four we can't have `make-it-go-zoom`. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13247/retag-request-the-optimizations

Comment: It's a character limit not a word limit

Comment: I think if you're typing and you hit said character limit, your browser should start playing "Stop in the Name of Love."

Comment: @Eric: Or it should play Stop...Hammertime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

tags are <del>25</del> 35 chars max

{[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/337838)}

Comment: mfmailcomposeviewcontroller is pretty key to sending email on the iphone. Had a hard time finding questions on it, cause it gets truncated to [mfmailcomposeviewcontroll] and I obviously searched for [mfmailcomposeviewcontroller]. For those that don't know, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller is an iOS class, not a concatenation of terms, so there wouldn't be a way to shorten it. Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 9):

Is there really a need for 3.5sp1? How rapidly does the functionality of SQL Server Compact change? Personally I'm against version tags unless the software isn't backwards compatible. Tags should be kept as general as they can, then further restrict the parameters inside the question. I fear the day if tags ever become like what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

To give an update, tag limit were increased in 2017 to 35 chars, as seen on Shog9's answer [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/337838)

> So as of this afternoon, the maximum length of a tag name is 35
>   characters on all sites. Use those extra 10 characters wisely!