# Maximum length of tags

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many words can a tag contain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain)

Is there a maximum limit on the length of tags? I noticed that the tag for SQL Server Management Studio is truncated to `sql-server-management-stu`.

It seems like this should be an easy thing to correct, if not to allow the creation of new longer tags, but to correct existing tags that have been truncated.

Comment: How often are you going to want tags longer than 25 characters?

Comment: This seems to be a question turning into a feature request that is marked as duplicate of a question. This question is then in turn marked as a duplicate of a full feature request. Leading to no feaure request thats actually open. I've tried to sort this out by editing this into a question and voting to reopen the [full feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209248/increase-limit-on-tag-length)

Answer (score 3):

It would be logical to conclude that the maximum tag length is 25, which seems quite reasonable.  In the example you gave, that could be renamed `sql-server-mgmt-studio`.