# Should the maximum tag length be increased?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How many words can a tag contain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain)
>   [Maximum length of tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32746/maximum-length-of-tags)

Currently, the maximum tag length is [25 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain/13274#13274). This gives tags such as "interprocess-communicatio" (also shortened to the tag ipc).

Should this be increased, or should the truncated tag be renamed?

Comment: This is a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32746/maximum-length-of-tags-closed and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain

Comment: Duplicate? I mean other two are about knowing maximum length and this is a request to increase it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No matter what the limit is, you can always find examples which exceeds it. Just ask me, I'm German, I concatenate the shit out of you!

Rename it, that's it! 25 chars sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: ah yes, the Germans and their long words... Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz !! http://courses.csusm.edu/grmn201mh/long%20words.htm

Comment: @Jeff: pretty small words...

Comment: Meh, that might work for SO, but definitely not on [movies.se]. I agree that one can always find examples to want a higher limit, but c'mon, 25? 40 wouldn't hurt anyone either. It just happens too often that the tag space is too small and there isn't a reasonable way to split or shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

Break it up into two tags and include the IPC tag as well.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing or IPC would be good for most people