# Maximum text limit for TAG lose the meaning

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, tags, character-limit

I've been reading these questions,

[How many words can a tag contain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain)

[Maximum length of tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32746/maximum-length-of-tags)

however I am adding one more question to talk on this limit. I know 25 is the maximum limit for any tag created. However there should be some mechanism that allow / differentiate with code (snippets) default keyword and the newly created tag. 
Logically there's no difference, but in practical use, I can show you the difference:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428886/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-ios-4-3-cant-stream-m3u8-file See this question I've just asked, where I was trying to add a tag for `MPMoviePlayerViewController` which is an iOS SDK keyword (reserved word), but I can't add it fully as there's a limit of 25 characters maximum. I feel this is not be the correct limitation for developers. Personally I feel this bad if I lost meaning of a word.

Is there any mechanism, that recognizes those tags which are reserve word so that they would be shown fully and not the cut-ed out.

Comment: Why should that keyword be a tag?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: Search works way better these days, likely meaning a tag that long is not necessary even if we would want to allow it.

Comment: I'm not seeing why that should even be a tag in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit for tags is pure practical. And I think 25 is perfect.

There is no need to include a tag for each keyword or identifier. If you have a problem with a language,  add the language tag and the version tag (if needed). If the item of your worries belongs to a specific framework or library, include that too. But more levels are not really needed.

Besides, what to do with keywords/identifiers that have a meaning in several languages... we already have problems with tags that can be interpreted in several ways.

Comment: What about the recreational sites? Where series or game names can have very long names? (assassins-creed-brotherhood)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: they use [`[ac-brotherhood]`](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-brotherhood) and [`[assassins-creed-series]`](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-series).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: That was just an example. Here's a better one: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/464/how-should-we-tag-hentai-ji-to-warawanai-neko

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I can see that the limit can be a problem in some rare cases, but I assume that it will be rare (a little bit less rare in some communities, but still rare there).

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` is *not* a keyword, it's an identifier, the name of a class, and it shouldn't be made a tag. Tags are for broad categorization, not for adding each and every keyword/identifier contained in your code to your question a *second time*. Full text searches will allow people to find your question based on the string "MPMoviePlayerViewController", it does nothing for you or anybody else to add it as a tag as well.