# Failed to create a tag NSDistributedNotificationCenter due to 25 limit

Tags: discussion, tags

I failed to create one tag (class name) from Cocoa `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190517/nsdistributednotification-to-a-cocoa-console-app). And forced to truncate the `Center` from end, this will surely create issues with people working with objective-c & cocoa.

Suggestions are required from your side, how to deal with this.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Could you suggest me where to go for this?

Comment: the 25 character limit issue and not able to form a proper tag.

Comment: Why do you want to create such tag?

Comment: Because there is one such class :p

Comment: Why need to create a tag for a class? Doesn't this one fit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsnotificationcenter

Comment: I really don't see a need to create a separate tag for every possible class that exists in every possible programming language.

Comment: there are some differences between Distributed and normal notifications, isn't it? Since there are many tags for different versions of applications, classes etc.

Comment: @IanKemp: This helps to filter out the questions quickly.

Comment: You just have to upvote [this existing feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209248/increase-limit-on-tag-length) and keep bumping it with bounties until it's done. No other way, since even devs can't create tag that exceeds the limit.

Answer (score 6):

I see a few problems with that tag:

1. You don't want to create a tag for each and every class name in any framework. There is usually not that much use in tagging your question with a specific class name.
2. The length of the class name can be a problem too. While the maximum length is set on 25, which is an arbitrary number of course, I don't think that should be increased just to fit in some lengthy tag names. They will eat up the entire screen, certainly on mobile devices. Where to stop is the question then. 35? 50?

You should check if the tag should really be there. If so, try to shorten it.