# Add blue color background to bounty award on the Mobile UI

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, bounties, mobile-web

As I was browsing through the questions list on the main page of Meta.SE on my mobile (iPhone 6 with iOS 8.4), I came across the [Increase limit on tag length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209248/increase-limit-on-tag-length) question with an open bounty of +100 points in a blue background.

Here is the screenshot of the bounty question:
[image]

Nothing is wrong in the above screenshot. The question with a bounty award points in a blue background caught my eyes while scrolling down the list. The question really stood out from the rest. But, upon opening this bounty question, I found two places where the display of bounty points was missing (circled in *Red*) the blue background. Here are the screenshots of those two places.

## 1. At the end of the question:

[image]

## 2. Under the votes section of "Tshepang" answer:

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshots, especially on the "Tshepang" answer, displaying just "+25" without the blue color background looks very *plain*. There are already four answers (and could be more in the future) for this question. Adding this little UI tweak will not only catch the eyes but also help easily identify the award winning answer. It's just a matter of adding/applying the existing (the one currently used on the main page) .class CSS property to it and that would take care of it. No need of adding any extra CSS code or whatsoever. But, that's just my opinion. SE's front-end development team might have a better solution to achieve this and I would go along with it as all I care is to see this gets implemented.

I would like to make a feature request to add the blue color background to the bounty award points on the Mobile UI. This will also make the UI more ***consistent*** across the different devices.

**Mock-ups:** (Because *A picture is worth a thousand words.*)
[image]

and,

[image]

Please note that I am not a graphics design expert, the above mock-ups are just to get an idea of what it would look like if the proposed feature-request gets implemented. Please share your thoughts or/and any ideas that can help improve this proposal.

Comment: 2, maybe. 1 meh to couldn't care less.

Comment: For awarded bounty on answer I agree. But big bright yellow bounty box needs no blue to be visible. It already is.

Comment: @Mołot Yes, me too and that's why if you see my question focuses more on the awarded bounty to answer.