# Realtime character counter at /tags/$tagname/synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

When you're trying to come up with a creative synonym for a thing with a long name, it is a real pain in the butt when you think you've finally come up with something that's short enough to fit, and then you click on "Suggest" at [/tags/$tagname/synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/synonyms), and then that godforsaken red box comes up and laughs at you with its wretched

> The tag '$tagsynonym' is too long; the maximum length is 25 characters

Now, obviously, the best thing to do would be to [just increase the length limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259377/) - but until you do that, could we at least get a running character counter for the tag synonym suggestion field, like the one we have for comments?

(Also, while we're here, could the error message *please* tell us what the length of the proposed synonym is? Currently, to figure out how many characters over I am, I'm forced to copy-paste it into my browser's dev console and do a `"...".length` like some kind of neanderthal.)