# Is there a character limit for job skills on careers?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I've been working on my resume on the Careers site and am having an issue adding "blackberry-enterprise-server" as a technology under an experience block. The problem is that when it's added the string gets truncated to read "blackberry-enterprise-ser". Seems like a column is set too short or something.

Anyway, kind of a problem because I can't, you know, add technology to my experience.

(BTW, yes, I know I could use BES instead of "blackberry-enterprise-server" but in my experience HR people tend to read from a list so it makes sense to me to use the whole string.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a 25-character limit for all tags.

See [How many words can a tag contain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain)