# Correct spelling of [nsfetchedresultscontrolle] to [nsfetchedresultscontroller] then merge synonym

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

This is a request to fix and then merge one tag for `NSFetchedResultsController`.

**Steps:**

1. Correct the spelling of [nsfetchedresultscontrolle](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontrolle)  x 805 to [nsfetchedresultscontroller].
2. Merge [nsfetchedresultcontroller](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultcontroller) x 88 into the newly corrected tag from step 1.

Comment: Why not make it a tag synonym of the correctly spelled one?

Answer (score 7):

This is currently practically impossible, as far as I know. The maximum tag length [is 25 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13274/161198). That is the whole reason behind the "misspelling" of [nsfetchedresultscontrolle](/questions/tagged/nsfetchedresultscontrolle).

So the options are to either allow longer tags, or to simply choose the most common one and retag the other questions to that.

Comment: I was not aware of the maximum length until you pointed it out. Can the tag with 88 posts be merged in?

Comment: Yes, 25 is the [maximum length in the tags table](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

Comment: @BryanLuby I'm sure that's possible. But given the relatively low number of questions with that tag, perhaps a manual effort and overall cleanup might not be a bad idea either?

Comment: @Bart I don't have retagging privileges yet. Plus I don't want to flood the review queue with 88 edits and swamp the front page.